# Covering Spaces of Wedge of two Circles

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I am working on some qual questions, and I don't really comprehend this. Let $X = S^{1} V S^{1}$. The question is asking about covering spaces 7,9, 11, and 12.

a. Determine whether or not the corresponding subgroup of $\pi_{1}(X)$ is normal.

c. Compute the deck group of the covering space.

> For part (a), Hatcher says "the covering spaces with maximal symmetry are normal" and then rattles off which of them are normal; however, he never defines maximal symmetry so I don't really understand.
>
> For part (c) I am pretty stuck. I am not sure what to do.

Please help.

Thank You [image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkAyo.png)

Comment: Nobody can help?

Comment: I suggest you read the section on deck transformations and group actions in Hatcher. It explains everything you want to know pretty explicitly there. I mean, that section even starts off with the answer to your first question.

Comment: I know he talks about it. The point is that I don't understand Hatcher's so called "explanation" because his "explanations" are usually just a statement of conclusions.

Comment: The answer to both your questions is the first proposition in that section, which has a proof. I don't know what other kind of explanations you want.